# How to get a variable to wrap NSUserDefaults objects?

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults

I'd like to abstract the underlying storage away, so I'd like to create a variable with getters/setters for NSUserDefaults values. Below I was able to do this with the getter like this and even handle default values:

```
public let userStorage = NSUserDefaults(suiteName: "group.testabcxyz")

public var categories: [String] {
    get {
        // Get from storage or default
        if userStorage?.objectForKey("category") == nil {
            // Set defaults
            userStorage?.setObject([
                "Weight",
                "Length",
                "Volume"
            ], forKey: "category")
            userStorage?.synchronize()
        }

        return userStorage?.objectForKey("category") as! [String]
    }
    set {
        // Set new value in storage
        userStorage?.setObject(newValue, forKey: "category")
        userStorage?.synchronize()
    }
}
```

Now I'm having trouble syncing the array back to `userStorage` when rearranging the items such as doing something like this:

```
    var itemToMove = categories[sourceIndexPath.row]

    // Move record in array
    categories.removeAtIndex(sourceIndexPath.row)
    categories.insert(itemToMove, atIndex: destinationIndexPath.row)
```

What's confusing me is in this case I'm not setting the value back if you notice. I am just using `removeAtIndex` and `insert`, which do not call `userStorage?.synchronize()` anywhere since I didn't really `set` anything. Is what I'm trying to do possible or any implications to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Property setters have an implicit variable called `newValue` represents, unsurprisingly, the new value being assigned to that property:

```
public let userStorage = NSUserDefaults(suiteName: "group.testabcxyz")
public var categories: [String] {
    get {
        // Get from storage or default
        if userStorage?.objectForKey("category") == nil {
            // Set defaults
            userStorage?.setObject([
                "Weight",
                "Length",
                "Volume"
            ], forKey: "category")
            userStorage?.synchronize()
        }
        return userStorage?.objectForKey("category") as! [String]
    }
    set {
        // Set new value in storage
        userStorage?.setObject(newValue, forKey: "category")
        userStorage?.synchronize()
    }
}
```

This would work with your example usage, because when you call `categories.removeAtIndex(sourceIndexPath.row)` it mutates the array and causes the setter to be called.

You can find more info about computed properties in the [Computed Properties](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH14-ID254) section of the Swift Programming Language

Comment: Thx I think I simplified it too much. I updated the question with a more complex scenario that was the one that confused me in my app.

Comment: Ok, but the question is still essentially the same - you have just changed the variable from type `Bool`, to type `[String]`. I've edited the answer to match.

Comment: But I'm not setting the value back if you notice. I am just using `removeAtIndex` and `insert`, which do not call `userStorage?.synchronize()` anywhere since I didn't really set anything correct?

Comment: Ah, I see you've edited it again ;). I've edited the answer. Mutating an array will cause its setter to be called.

Comment: Calling `synchronize()` is not necessary and not recommended unless you're in one of the few scenarios where Apple says it's okay.

Comment: As @JonShier says, it is not necessary to call `synchronize()` as it is called periodically by the system. However I'd say there's no real harm in calling it manually - any performance penalty for a small amount of data such as this would be negligible, and calling it manually ensures the data is synched in the case of a crash (for example).

Comment: Except for the fact that calling it manually goes against Apple's recommended usage and isn't necessary (don't write code for no reason), I'd agree.